# MySQL results ranking

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table called enrol with the following columns: student, subject, mark, year:

```
student subject mark    year
John    Mathematics 70  2013
Peter   Mathematics 87  2013
James   Mathematics 69  2013
Paul    Mathematics 50  2013
Judas   Mathematics 77  2013
Jude    Mathematics 99  2013
Michael Mathematics 48  2013
Matthew Mathematics 50  2013
```

I want to get the rank for the marks, let's say for example John WHERE subject='Mathematics' AND year='2013'

How do I write this SQL statement?

Answer (score 0):

Not great with MySQL myself but should be as follows if I am following your question correctly:

```
SELECT * FROM 'enrol' WHERE student='John' AND subject='Mathematics' AND year='2013' ORDER BY 'mark' DESC
```

This will select the result for someone called John who does Mathmaatics and in year 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly...

```
SELECT student
     , rank 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , IF(@prev<>mark,@i:=@i+1,@i:=@i) rank
            , @prev:=mark 
         FROM my_table x
            , (SELECT @i:=0,@prev:='') vars 
        WHERE year = 2013 
          AND subject = 'mathematics' 
        ORDER 
           BY mark DESC
     ) n 
 WHERE student = 'John';
```